# How to add user to a group in admin

Tags: python, html, django

Since the default django admin group form does not have field for selecting users in a group. I Wrote down some codes which i got online to add the selected users field.Everything is working just fine. Until i tried saving the group form i created, I get this error 'Group' object has no attribute 'user_set'

```
class GroupAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=group
        exclude=[]
    users=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User,objects.all(),widget=FilteredSelectMultiple('users',False),required=False)
   def __int__(self,*args,**kwargs):
       super(GroupAdminForm,self).__int__(*args,**kwargs)
       if self.instance.pk:
           self.fields['users'].initial=self.instance.user_set.all()
   def save_m2m(self):
       self.instance.user_set.set(self.cleaned_data['users'])
   def save(self,*args,*kwargs):
       instance= super(GroupAdminForm,self).save()
       self.save_m2m()
       return instance
```

I am getting this error 'Group' object has no attribute 'user_set' . I donot know on how to go about resolving this problem . Please help . I am navies in django.   Help Hlep please

Comment: try to use **`user`** instead of **`user_set`**

Comment: `Group' object has no attribute 'user_set'` this error is showing that User model has no related object with Group model. Maybe adding ForeignKey with Group model inside  User model would sort it.

Comment: Alright brother , let me give a try

Comment: It is not working . How should i add a foreign key , please give me a code presentation

Comment: I did it the error stopped . But successful users added to the group , do not save after saving the group . So what i my doing wrong in my code . please help . Thanks